# Extension of adding rolling coupon expiration dates

Tags: coupon-codes

So I've been asked to come up with a sale where each customer receives a couppon that expires 30 DAYS after they receive it...not 30 days from the beginning of the promotion.

The other limitation I have is that the email is triggered by an extension that calls a shopping card rule, so I really need an extension that modifies this in the shopping cart price rule section of Magento.

Any thoughts or suggestions on an extension for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So if you have an extension that sends emails, you can create a new shopping cart rule for each email when you need the coupon. Then you can remove the unused codes by cron job for example.